# Return data as String

Tags: java

I use this code to download an image from Angular FE:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/company_logo/{job_id}",method= RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable int job_id) throws IOException {

        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("color.jpg");
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

But I would like to return the image not as a `byte[]` but as String. What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: Images aren't strings. Unless you encode their bytes as a string, for example using base64.

Comment: Can you show me how, please?

Comment: The correct answer is "don't". The correct data type for binary data is `byte[]`.

Comment: hm.... in Angular what type of object should be used to store the image? blob?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you want to return binary data such as an image over HTTP, you do a Base64 encoding on the binary information and return it as a string.

In java, this is provided as a part of the standard library. In your case, you may elect to use the [Base64.Encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-) class methods, and just return those. The browser should recognize based on response headers that the information is encoded.

Comment: Something like `return Base64.encodeToString(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), Base64.DEFAULT);`?

Comment: I don't see any overload for `Base64.encodeToString()` that takes two parameters. Are you perhaps using the Android Base64 class for some reason?

Comment: What about this: `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));`

Comment: I don't have a JVM handy to give you a definitive yes/no on that. Perhaps try running it.